# Buy and sell-markers on lower time frames when longer time frame shows uptrend

Tags: charts, pine-script

So, I'm trying to run a trading bot on medium timeframes (1h - 4h) using the KDJ-indicator. I know it's not the most responsive indicator but it is very reliable, at least on higher time frames (8h - 1D).
What I would like to be able to do is use the following script to send BUY/SELL-signals to my bot, BUT ONLY when the asset is not trending down on the 1D-chart. In other words, I would like to run this script:

```
//@version=4
study(title="KDJ IndicatorTV", shorttitle="KDJ_TV", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="", overlay=true)
periodK = input(9, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input(5, title="D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
multiplierJ = input(3.5, title="Jx", minval=0.1)
k = ema(stoch(hlc3, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = ema(k, periodD)
j = multiplierJ * k-2 * d

makeShape1 = if (crossover(j,d) or crossover(j,99))
    true
else
    false

plotshape(series=makeShape1, style=shape.cross, color=#0094FF, transp=10, text="buy", title='buy')

makeShape2 = if (crossunder(j,d) or crossunder(j,99))
    true
else
    false
    
plotshape(series=makeShape2, style=shape.cross, color=#FF6A00, transp=10, text="sell", title='sell')
//end
```

And I would like to add a condition to makeShape1, something like "AND If j>d on 1D-chart", to ensure that buys are only generated while J is larger than D on the 1D-chart of that asset (ie: when the market for that asset is in an uptrend).

Any ideas on if/how I can achieve that?

Thanks!
-Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access higher TFs with `security()` function

```
//@version=4
study(title="KDJ IndicatorTV", shorttitle="KDJ_TV", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="", overlay=true)
periodK = input(9, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input(5, title="D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
multiplierJ = input(3.5, title="Jx", minval=0.1)
k = ema(stoch(hlc3, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = ema(k, periodD)
j = multiplierJ * k-2 * d

j_sec = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", j) // 1 day time frame for j
d_sec = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", d) // 1 day time frame for d

makeShape1 = if (crossover(j,d) or crossover(j,99)) and j_sec > d_sec
    true
else
    false

plotshape(series=makeShape1, style=shape.cross, color=#0094FF, transp=10, text="buy", title='buy')

makeShape2 = if (crossunder(j,d) or crossunder(j,99))
    true
else
    false
    
plotshape(series=makeShape2, style=shape.cross, color=#FF6A00, transp=10, text="sell", title='sell')
//end
```

Comment: Wow - thanks a lot. That's exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @DanielBauer great, don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as solved/accepted :)